# In Spring Web Flow skip browser back button for specific page OR Flow

Tags: javascript, html, spring-mvc, spring-webflow, spring-webflow-2

Sorry if question is not so clear. and please do let me know if any such issues reported earlier. I tried searching on google a lot but didn't find proper solution.

Please see issue in use case below

I have 3 flows

1. Search - Searching items
2. View - Viewing Details
3. Edit - Add/Edit Specific Item and Save into DB

Here is navigation between flows using subFlow state and end state

- Search -- using subFlow state to --> View
- Edit -- using subFlow state to --> View
- Search -- using end state to --> Edit
- View -- using end state to --> Edit

I have problem with navigation through browser back button.
When I edit something in Edit flow and move to View Flow to show edited Item. on view when I press browsers back button It try to navigate me to Edit flow url. I want to eliminate all edit activities from client when I submit the form finally.

Here is desired result

- Moving from Search to View and press back button it lends me to
  search page which is fine and required.
- Moving from Edit to View and
  press button **IT SHOULD LEND ME TO SEARCH PAGE** which is not happening
  right now. There should no reference of edit in back button operation.

Here is Edit Web flow code

```
<!-- Step 2 -->
<view-state id="finalPage" view="final_page" model="form">
    <transition on="submit" to="submit" history="invalidate" />
    <transition on="cancel" to="cancel" history="invalidate" />
    <transition on="previous" to="reShowConfig" />
</view-state>

<!-- Actions -->
<action-state id="submit">
    <evaluate expression="Doing some saving activity" result="flowScope.saveStatus" />
    <transition on="success" to="view">
</action-state>

<subflow-state id="view" subflow="viewFlow" >
    <input name="id" value="id" />
    <input name="message" value="'The data is saved successfully!'" />
</subflow-state>
```

Any server side or client side solutions are appreciated.
I struggled a lot to find solution but no luck.

Comment: Browser "back" only goes back to a previous URL. Which is the snapshot before this one. Which is on the still-valid "finalPage" state in the Edit flow, correct? Your history invalidate removes the prior snapshots, but not that one.

Comment: Yes exactly. Any solution on this?

Comment: That's how browser back works, so it'll be more of a workaround than a solution, IMO. Plus, making back do something other than... well... back... could be confusing/disruptive to users. https://ux.stackexchange.com/a/7913/12841

Comment: Getting your point but what work around I could do? I tried to send form as post on edit link instead of link as get. hoping it will not cached. But In webflow the request redirected through Search flow and I guess it sends intermediate page to redirect to send edit request. May be I'll need to look more deep.

Comment: you could set a variable (in edit) and check for that variable value to go back to search